# How do I draw an array of graphics objects?

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, jpanel

So I have been pulling my hair out over this assignment for quite some time now, and I could really use some help. I have to create a rectangle graphics object in a super class, then extend that class into a subclass, that then draws 7 of said rectangles to draw a number like you would see on a calculator. I am  creating an array of rectangles in the subclass and trying to add them to a panel, however I keep getting errors for all the ways I try to add to the panel. Any help would be appreciated immensely.

This is my super class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Bar extends JPanel {
public Color myColor;
Graphics g;
int x;
int y;
int w;
int h;

public Bar(int newX, int newY, int newW, int newH) {
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
    w = newW;
    h = newH;
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(getColor());
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

public Color getColor() {
    return myColor;
}
}
```

and then my subclass

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LED extends Bar {
public static Bar[] myLED;
public static int number;
public boolean isOn;


public LED(Bar[] myLED) {
    super(10, 10, 15, 45);
    switch(number) {
        case 0: myLED[0] = new Bar(10, 10, 15, 45);
            isOn = true;
    }
}

public void setOn(boolean isOn) {
    if(isOn = true) {
        myColor = Color.GREEN;
    }
    else 
        myColor = Color.BLACK;
}

public static Bar[] getLED() {
    return myLED;
}

public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Calculator");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 500, 500);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(myLED); //I'm getting an error on this line, as well as the one below this.
    window.getContentPane().add(myLED);//getContentPane().
    window.setVisible(true);
}   
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Please gives us the errors you are getting :)

Comment: Both of you, the error is properly in the code. As for the fix, try adding a `LED myLED = new LED()` just before the errors.

Comment: You don't have a `myLed` variable inside a static method such as `main`. The problem in this project goes way beyond that, though. It's planned incorrectly. Are you sure the definition of the task said a LED object had to extend a Bar object? It makes no sense as there is no is_A relation between these entities. Can you give us the exact wording they used?

Comment: Thanks for the replys everyone. The errors were no suitable method found for add(). I tried adding    LED myLED = new LED() but then it wants me to pass a Bar[] as a parameter. When I do that, I get a null pointer exception error at run time. 
The instructions for this say to make LED extend Bar. I agree it seems pointless, but that's the way it has to be done.